# how to import external rsa public key in openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa

I would like to perform operations such as RSA signature verification through an RSA public key file received from an external server.
Key values are given in der format or pem format as follows.

```
der:"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"

pem_base64:"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAirjFSROMxZ9gW1AmX2nsO4zjs+mvXhdNJs/iQmUBBL6gUQEYlnbHopLMa1rnGeEZ46wp6dOtna3NpJby9xhfnAxIcqLbEk8BmSsjjoP9WC2KKQ8pc/nPdE8eU/iqU6IlwSKZscw2WPtgfLWrpXmDLWwmh/cTAKTfPfHBQH4X0ipcGcgw7QxYJAcjCaYSuz5PsznyW7vP4pmfQ0IRBkmrrF9L/qKlnNOMFzl5pnmv3Iuqy06H61Cs+AbPt0B1BL2sEQz7y5nAQicDHhRrnzuDd8hwNWkDCfrphy4se5PoN1/M3rxPmL4dV0JpxROkNZT2uIYfdGSDKumeus6uD8w6xQIDAQAB"
```

I want to import the above data into **"struct rsa_st * rsa"**, but it is not working.

For example, to import the rsa public key in der format, I did the following:

```
==========================================================
char data[] = "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";

unsigned char * pArr = (unsigned char *)malloc(buf_len);
RSA *pub_rsa = NULL;

fnStr2Hex(pArr, data); // Converts a data array composed of strings to a hex array (pArr).
pub_rsa=d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL,&pArr,(long)buf_len);
==========================================================
```

In this case, In **d2i_RSAPublicKey** function is returning NULL Pointer.
I do not know what went wrong.

And I do not know how to change the string data received by pem_base64 to **"struct rsa_st * rsa"** as well.
The sample code uses a function called **"ReadPublicKey"**, which seems to load an X.509 certificate file.

I do not read the file, but I need to get the data from the server like above.

Please answer the person who knows about this.

Comment: Are you sure you have a public key and not x509 public key cert

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not (just) an RSA PublicKey as defined by PKCS1 republished as [RFC8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.1) but an X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo as defined by X.509 republished as [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) *containing* the RSA publickey as defined by [RFC3279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3.1). OpenSSL calls this X.509 structure PUBKEY. **Use [d2i_RSA_PUBKEY](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/d2i_RSA_PUBKEY.html).**

Also:

- your posted code doesn't show where `buf_len` comes from. Make sure it's correct.
- your posted code sets `pArr` to point to malloc'ed space, then passes `&pArr` as `ppin` to a `d2i` routine. The `d2i` routines *change* the pointer that `ppin` points to, so it no longer points at the malloc'ed space. If you now try to `free(pArr)` it is undefined behavior according to the C standard, and in practice is likely to either crash or corrupt your heap and cause other seemingly unrelated things to be wrong or fail; if you don't `free` it it's a memory leak.
- PEM format is NOT just base64 of DER. It is base64 of DER, broken into lines terminated by line terminators, with header and trailer lines (dashes, BEGIN/END, type, dashes) added; these are part of the format and not optional. There optionally can be an 822-style header block, but that is not applicable here. Base64 of DER can be useful, but it is NOT PEM.

---

Meta: please add additional information about your question to your question. Stackexchange is designed to have the question in the question and the answer(s) in the answer(s), among other reasons because answers are not kept in time sequence. I thought there was a helpcenter page on this, but if so I can't now find it.

Anyway, you say your 'current' code is:

```
void fnStr2Hex(char* out, char* in) { 
        int data_len = strlen(in); 
        char * pStr = in; 
        int i; 

        for(i=0; i<data_len/2; i++) { 
                char buf[3] = {0,}; 
                memcpy(buf, pStr, sizeof(buf)); 

                out[i] = (unsigned char)strtol(buf, NULL, 16); 

                // need to check strol 2nd arguments... for error checking.. 
                printf("i:%d, pArr[i]:%02X \n", i, out[i]); 

                pStr+=2; 
        } 
} 

int main() { 
        char raw_data[] = 
"30819F300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818D0030818902818100AA18ABA43B50DEEF38598FAF87D2AB634E4571C130A9BCA7B878267414FAAB8B471BD8965F5C9FC3818485EAF529C26246F3055064A8DE19C8C338BE5496CBAEB059DC0B358143B44A35449EB264113121A455BD7FDE3FAC919E94B56FB9BB4F651CDB23EAD439D6CD523EB08191E75B35FD13A7419B3090F24787BD4F4E19670203010001"; 

        int data_len = strlen(raw_data);  
        unsigned char * pArr = (unsigned char *)malloc(data_len); 
        memset(pArr, 0x00, data_len); 

// raw_data is a string. Not in hex state. So I changed the contents of 
raw_data [] to hex in pArr. 
// The implementation of this function is above main function. 
        fnStr2Hex(pArr, raw_data); 

        STDout=BIO_new_fp(stdout,BIO_NOCLOSE); 

        pub_rsa=d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL,&pArr,(long)data_len); 

        if(pub_rsa == NULL) { 
                printf(&quot;error : failed d2i_RSAPublicKey \n&quot;); 
                return -1; 
        } 

        BN_print(STDout,pub_rsa->n);   // print modulus bignum 
        BN_print(STDout,pub_rsa->e);  //  print exponent bignum 

        return 0; 
}
```

This is not compilable; it has a broken comment, does not declare `STDout` and `pub_rsa`, and does not have the needed `#include`'s. Fixing these leaves the following problems:

1. (big) **your hex conversion is wrong**. It copies 3 characters at a time from the hex string, so it whereas the converted bytes should be hex 30 81 9F etc, it actually computes on my system (and probably most) 08 19 F3 etc, which is totally wrong. Since it accesses at least one byte outside any valid object, in theory it could do even worse. Your 'checking' `printf` shows you this if you look at it.
2. (small) your allocation is wrong. First it is never necessary in C to cast the return value of `malloc` (or `realloc` or `calloc`) and sometimes (but not here) harmful; [see the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html). Second although the *hex* string is 324 characters (plus the terminating null) you only need 162 bytes to contain the decoded result (also shown by your 'checking' `printf`). However, since `d2i` ignores superfluous trailing data this does no harm. Plus you still have the issue of freeing it as I described previously.
3. (big) As I previously said, `d2i_RSAPublicKey` is the wrong routine; it expects a particular data format (PKCS1) which you do not have. **The correct routine for this data is `d2i_RSA_PUBKEY`**.
4. (small) your error handling is poor. When an OpenSSL routine returns a failure indication, in nearly all cases it also stores detailed error information in the 'error queue'. The easiest way to display this information is with [`ERR_print_errors_fp`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/ERR_print_errors.html) although there are more complicated ways if you prefer. For best results you need to have previously loaded the error strings usually by [`ERR_load_crypto_strings`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/ERR_load_crypto_strings.html) or in 1.1.0+ [`OPENSSL_init_crypto`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/OPENSSL_init_crypto.html) or variants of either that also cover SSL (which you currently aren't using and don't need). Although in this case, before fixing `d2i_RSAPublicKey`, the error queue gives you a description internal to the ASN.1 decoding routines, which you probably wouldn't have understood anyway -- although it might have at least pointed you in the direction of looking at the ASN.1 format.

Your code with those fixes does correctly print the modulus and exponent in hex as:

```
AA18ABA43B50DEEF38598FAF87D2AB634E4571C130A9BCA7B878267414FAAB8B471BD8965F5C9FC3818485EAF529C26246F3055064A8DE19C8C338BE5496CBAEB059DC0B358143B44A35449EB264113121A455BD7FDE3FAC919E94B56FB9BB4F651CDB23EAD439D6CD523EB08191E75B35FD13A7419B3090F24787BD4F4E196710001
```

Since you didn't put any separator you have to know the length of each portion to read this correctly.

However, this will not work in OpenSSL version 1.1.0 or later. The API has been changed so you can [no longer directly access fields like `n` and `e` in `RSA`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/RSA_get0_n.html) (which is a typedef ror `struct rsa_st`).

You then propose the following for PEM format:

```
raw_data[] = { 
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"\ 
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAirjFSROMxZ9gW1AmX2ns"\ 
"O4zjs+mvXhdNJs/iQmUBBL6gUQEYlnbHopLMa1rnGeEZ46wp6dOtna3NpJby9xhf"\ 
"nAxIcqLbEk8BmSsjjoP9WC2KKQ8pc/nPdE8eU/iqU6IlwSKZscw2WPtgfLWrpXmD"\ 
"LWwmh/cTAKTfPfHBQH4X0ipcGcgw7QxYJAcjCaYSuz5PsznyW7vP4pmfQ0IRBkmr"\ 
"rF9L/qKlnNOMFzl5pnmv3Iuqy06H61Cs+AbPt0B1BL2sEQz7y5nAQicDHhRrnzuD"\ 
"d8hwNWkDCfrphy4se5PoN1/M3rxPmL4dV0JpxROkNZT2uIYfdGSDKumeus6uD8w6"\ 
"xQIDAQAB"\ 
"-----END PUBLIC KEY----- " };
```

This is also wrong. In addition to the missing datatype (formally declaration specifier) `char`, the preprocessor line-wrap syntax

```
"ABC"\
"DEF"\
"GHI"
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
"ABC" "DEF" "GHI"
```

which because adjacent string literals are combined is exactly equivalent to

```
"ABCDEFGHI"
```

and does not contain any line terminators as required. What you need is to put at least LF characters, and ideally CR and LF characters, *in* the string values, which in C can be done portably only by using the escape sequences `\n` and `\r`. (Although the PEM spec calls for CR LF, OpenSSL will work with only LF.) Thus you need:

```
char raw_data[] = { "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAirjFSROMxZ9gW1AmX2ns\n"
"O4zjs+mvXhdNJs/iQmUBBL6gUQEYlnbHopLMa1rnGeEZ46wp6dOtna3NpJby9xhf\n"
"nAxIcqLbEk8BmSsjjoP9WC2KKQ8pc/nPdE8eU/iqU6IlwSKZscw2WPtgfLWrpXmD\n"
"LWwmh/cTAKTfPfHBQH4X0ipcGcgw7QxYJAcjCaYSuz5PsznyW7vP4pmfQ0IRBkmr\n"
"rF9L/qKlnNOMFzl5pnmv3Iuqy06H61Cs+AbPt0B1BL2sEQz7y5nAQicDHhRrnzuD\n"
"d8hwNWkDCfrphy4se5PoN1/M3rxPmL4dV0JpxROkNZT2uIYfdGSDKumeus6uD8w6\n"
"xQIDAQAB\n"
"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n" };
```

(or the same without the `{ }` because initializing a character array with a single string literal is handled by C as a special case).

Next, your code tries to convert this data from hex, the same as for the previous case -- but PEM is *not* hex so this is completely wrong even after fixing the hex routine as above. This data is already in PEM format so you should simply use `BIO_new_mem_buf(raw_data, strlen(raw_data))` -- or as an optimization `BIO_new_mem_buf(raw_data,-1)` which does the `strlen` for you.

Finally, this has the same problem as above: you call `PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey` but the data you have is not in PKCS1 format; instead call `PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY`.

Again your code with those changes works.

Since this is SO I don't ask why you don't want to use the commandline functionality for this -- even though it would have taken only a second or two, instead of days.

Comment: Thanks dave_thompson,
I have more questions, so I posted as below.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose I am doing this is to find the modulus and exponent in the RSA 
public key. 
My sample code and the current results are shown below.

=========================================================

```
void fnStr2Hex(char* out, char* in) { 
        int data_len = strlen(in); 
        char * pStr = in; 
        int i; 

        for(i=0; i<data_len/2; i++) { 
                char buf[3] = {0,}; 
                memcpy(buf, pStr, sizeof(buf)); 

                out[i] = (unsigned char)strtol(buf, NULL, 16); 

                // need to check strol 2nd arguments... for error checking.. 
                printf("i:%d, pArr[i]:%02X \n", i, out[i]); 

                pStr+=2; 
        } 
} 

int main() { 
        char raw_data[] = 
"30819F300D06092A864886F70D010101050003818D0030818902818100AA18ABA43B50DEEF38598FAF87D2AB634E4571C130A9BCA7B878267414FAAB8B471BD8965F5C9FC3818485EAF529C26246F3055064A8DE19C8C338BE5496CBAEB059DC0B358143B44A35449EB264113121A455BD7FDE3FAC919E94B56FB9BB4F651CDB23EAD439D6CD523EB08191E75B35FD13A7419B3090F24787BD4F4E19670203010001"; 

        int data_len = strlen(raw_data);  
        unsigned char * pArr = (unsigned char *)malloc(data_len); 
        memset(pArr, 0x00, data_len); 

// raw_data is a string. Not in hex state. So I changed the contents of 
raw_data [] to hex in pArr. 
// The implementation of this function is above main function. 
        fnStr2Hex(pArr, raw_data); 

        STDout=BIO_new_fp(stdout,BIO_NOCLOSE); 

        pub_rsa=d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL,&pArr,(long)data_len); 

        if(pub_rsa == NULL) { 
                printf(&quot;error : failed d2i_RSAPublicKey \n&quot;); 
                return -1; 
        } 

        BN_print(STDout,pub_rsa->n);   // print modulus bignum 
        BN_print(STDout,pub_rsa->e);  //  print exponent bignum 

        return 0; 
}
```

result : error : failed d2i_RSAPublicKey 
I don't know why it falied.

And you said you need prefix and postfix to do PEM format. 
Is it right to configure as shown below?

```
raw_data[] = { 
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"\ 
"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAirjFSROMxZ9gW1AmX2ns"\ 
"O4zjs+mvXhdNJs/iQmUBBL6gUQEYlnbHopLMa1rnGeEZ46wp6dOtna3NpJby9xhf"\ 
"nAxIcqLbEk8BmSsjjoP9WC2KKQ8pc/nPdE8eU/iqU6IlwSKZscw2WPtgfLWrpXmD"\ 
"LWwmh/cTAKTfPfHBQH4X0ipcGcgw7QxYJAcjCaYSuz5PsznyW7vP4pmfQ0IRBkmr"\ 
"rF9L/qKlnNOMFzl5pnmv3Iuqy06H61Cs+AbPt0B1BL2sEQz7y5nAQicDHhRrnzuD"\ 
"d8hwNWkDCfrphy4se5PoN1/M3rxPmL4dV0JpxROkNZT2uIYfdGSDKumeus6uD8w6"\ 
"xQIDAQAB"\ 
"-----END PUBLIC KEY----- " };
```

After that, I coded as follows.

```
    int data_len = strlen(raw_data); 
        BIO *bufio = NULL; 
        RSA *pub_rsa = NULL; 

        unsigned char * pArr = (unsigned char *)malloc(data_len); 
        memset(pArr, 0x00, data_len); 

        fnStr2Hex(pArr, raw_data);  // for converting hex 

        bufio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)pArr, data_len); 

        if(bufio == NULL) { 
                printf("Error (1) \n"); 
                return -1; 
        } 

        PEM_read_bio_RSAPublicKey(bufio, &pub_rsa, 0, NULL); 

        if(pub_rsa == NULL) { 
                printf("Error (2) \n"); 
                return -1; 
        } 
} // end of main
```

When I execute the above code, Error (2) is output. 
I want to be helped with the above two (DER, PEM) situations. 
Again, I want to find the modulus and public exponent in the RSA public key. 
(I want to implement it in C code, not in shell command.)

BR,

Comment: This belongs in the question not an answer. See update to my answer.